# How to hide category name

Tags: categories, filters, hooks

I have a category about the catalog, news1 Which I use to get a post on the main page. The problem is that I don't want the news1 category name to appear in these posts, but I want other categories to be displayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend to use categories to show posts anywhere. Such approach has many consequences (it creates category archive, feeds, and so on).

But if you already have such solution, then you can use [`get_the_categories`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L97) filter and remove given category from the list.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_categories', function ( $categories, $id ) {
    foreach ( $categories as $i => $term ) {
        if ( <ID_OF_CATEGORY_TO_IGNORE> == $term->term_id ) {
            unset( $categories[$i] );
        }
    }
    return $categories;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you, that was it.

Comment: what solution do you suggest and place your posts anywhere ?

Comment: @HubertK-i it depends on requirements. Custom taxonomy (which is not public and doesn’t have archives)? Native featured posts?

Answer (score -2):

Just make the category status "private".  It should do the job and will not be visible publicly

Comment: There's no such thing as category statuses.